# MarkerWithLabel.js - labelText not creating text for the marker label?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to use MarkerWithLabel from the Google Maps Utility Library v3 as found here:

https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/markerwithlabel/examples/basic.html?r=131

The problem is however that the sample code produces what is in my mind an incorrect result. I say in my mind because i'm not sure exactly how the demo is supposed to work but surely not like this:

[image: Result of basic.html]

What I see there is just below the marker we have the container for the label with a black border and within the inline CSS in the example we have:

`border: 2px solid black;`

So this is what we are seeing below the marker on the map for sure. The problem though, is that when we define the marker before adding it to the map within the initMap() function we have:

```
var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
   position: homeLatLng,
   draggable: false,
   map: map,
   labelText: "$425K",
   labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
   labelStyle: {top: "0px", left: "-21px", opacity: 0.75},
   labelVisible: true
 });
```

More specifically:

`labelText: "$425K",`

Why is this not showing up on the map, in the DOM or in the CSS?

I see two possible ways of the text being there under the marker, it could be that the DOM is manipulated and the text is inserted within the highlighted `div` in the image or it could be that they use the CSS `before` selector to insert it. But there is neither happening in this example and I don't see the text anywhere.

I have tried previous versions of the API as suggested in other questions but to no avail, it does not work as I think it should.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here? It seems that support for this third party extension died some time ago and there is not very much information on this at all. Is there any other way for me to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a really old version of the library (r131).  Use the latest version:

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/examples/basic.html

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
     var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.47805, -123.84716);
     var homeLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.47805, -123.84716);

     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
       zoom: 12,
       center: latLng,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     });

     var marker1 = new MarkerWithLabel({
       position: homeLatLng,
       draggable: true,
       raiseOnDrag: true,
       map: map,
       labelContent: "$425K",
       labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
       labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
       labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75}
     });

     var marker2 = new MarkerWithLabel({
       position: new google.maps.LatLng(49.475, -123.84),
       draggable: true,
       raiseOnDrag: true,
       map: map,
       labelContent: "$395K",
       labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
       labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
       labelStyle: {opacity: 1.0}
     });

     var iw1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
       content: "Home For Sale"
     });
     var iw2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
       content: "Another Home For Sale"
     });
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, "click", function (e) { iw1.open(map, this); });
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, "click", function (e) { iw2.open(map, this); });
   }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initMap);
```

```css
   .labels {
     color: red;
     background-color: white;
     font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;
     font-size: 10px;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-align: center;
     width: 40px;
     border: 2px solid black;
     white-space: nowrap;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js"></script>
<p>A basic example of markers with labels. Note that an information window appears whether you
click the marker portion or the label portion of the MarkerWithLabel. The two markers shown here
are both draggable so you can easily verify that markers and labels overlap as expected.</p>
 <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 400px; width: 100%;"></div>
 <div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: I wish google would demote my bad link and old info, I tried on 1.1.9 and I didn't see the 1.1.10 revision. Thank you :-)